# Difficulty understanding "antichains"

Tags: order-theory

I'm having a difficulty understanding the concept of "antichains".

> An antichain in a poset $P$ is a  subset $C \subseteq P$ such that no 2 elements are comparable

I understand the definition, but I guess I'm having difficulty applying it to a real situation. For example, let's say I have the following set:

> $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ .

Here, let's define: $x\preceq y \Longleftrightarrow x$ divides $y$.

We can then find the following chains:

> $(1,2,4,8), \quad (1,3,9),\quad (1,5,10),\quad (1,2,10),\quad (1,2,6),\quad (1,3,6)$

What would the antichains be (if any)? My guess:

> $(1,5,6), \quad (1,5,9), \quad (1,7,10), \quad (1,7,9), \quad (1,3,10), \quad (1,5,7), \quad (1,3,8), \quad (1,3,4)$

etc. etc.

Am I on the right track or no? Is there a way to determine the number of antichains without figuring them all out yourself?

If this is a bad example, can someone give me a simple example?

Comment: Be careful, $1$ divides any number. Besides that, yes, those are antichains.

Comment: Okay. That's what I was wondering since 1 divides anything. Would (1,2,4,5) also be an antichain? 2 and 4 are related, but neither are related to 5.

Comment: No. No two elements in an antichain are related.

Comment: As a consequence, if an antichain contains $1$ then $1$ is in fact its only element.

Comment: Nop, in that particular poset no antichain would have $1$ as a member, besides $\{1\}$.  That is no an antichain, the definition says that for any $a,b\in A$, the antichain, you can not compare $a$ and $b$. There you can compare $1$ with all of them and $2$ with $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not bad, however there is a classic example of a [Lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29), which has a large number of antichains - it is a [Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). Sorry to say, the exact number of antichains is not known even in this classic case - it's famous and long-standing [Dedekind Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number).